# Template class and overloaded << operator

Tags: c++, templates, bind, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload << operator for some template class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class SampleClass {

public:
    SampleClass() = default;

    void Add(const T1 &key, const T2 &value)
    {
        database[key] = value;
    }

    typename std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator cbegin() const { return database.cbegin(); }
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator cend() const { return database.cend(); }


private:
    std::map<T1, T2> database;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> 
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, SampleClass<T1, T2> &rhs)
{
    for(auto el = rhs.cbegin(); el != rhs.cend(); el++)
        os << el->first << " " << el->second << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

The error that I'm getting from g++

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
    os << el->first << " " << el->second << std::endl;
```

I tried also declaring this operator as inline friend function but the result it the same also didn't work. Could anyone explain to me why it happens??

Update:
The thing is the compiler didn't tell me that the cass which i used as the value for the SampleClass didn't have overloaded << operator. I was still looking around in the SampleClass instead of checking other files. But thanks to you that told me that for built in types everything is ok i realized what is needed to be checked. Thank you and sorry for trouble.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/330f5f482c4500c9).

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad... I modified the original code and forgot to change the class name in the overloaded operator. The original one is a little bit too long to post and ask for checking ;) I also edited includes so everything should be ok now

Comment: @user3119781 Cannot reproduce [here](http://rextester.com/KEYF63866) too. How are you instantiating `SampleClass` ? It has to do with the types also the `overload <<` on those types

Comment: A little embarasment. I'm sorry but my class was using another class to instantiate SampleClass as value of the map. The class wasn't prepared by me but the thing is i didn't check if it has also << operator. The compiler didn't give me any clue to check in another file and that was why i was still looking around. Stupid mistakes are the hardest ones to find....

Comment: Happens. Voting to close then, if you don't mind.